# Count values of list from csv to table

Tags: python, arrays, csv

I am trying to create a program using Python, where I want a table which is created according to the data present in another table.
The data in the primary table does not have a pattern, and they are count of values from another table.

For example under (1,1) (row, column) the number is 15 which is the total number of 1's present in the first column of the second table. The range of the second table is 1-5 as rows and 1-10 as columns, and the tables are present in a CSV file.

[image representing the two tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AafGo.png)

```
import numpy as np

RangeNumber = 10
abcde = []
counta = 0
countb = 0

with open('loto1_count.csv', 'w+') as f:
    readCSV = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter=';'))
    for a in range(1, RangeNumber - 4):
        for b in range(a + 1, RangeNumber - 3):
            for c in range(b + 1, RangeNumber - 2):
                for d in range(c + 1, RangeNumber - 1):
                    for e in range(d + 1, RangeNumber):
                        abcde = [a, b, c, d, e]
                        val = str(abcde)

                        array1 = np.asarray(val)

                        if a == 1:
                            counta += 1
                        elif a == 2:
                            countb += 1


                        f.write(val1)


l = len(array1)
print(abcde)            
print(counta)
print(countb)
f.close
```

`

Above is the code that I tried creating the sum of numbers but the length increases as the count increase which would create a large number of variables and confusion.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Please post your code, what you have already tryed.

Comment: @HLupo, I have added the code in the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code works for you :)

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

row= defaultdict(list)

filename = 'file.csv'
with open(filename, 'r') as csvf:
    read = csv.reader(csvf)
    read.__next__()
    for line in read:
        for i in range(len(line)):
            row[i].append(line[i])

filename= 'new_csv.csv'

with open(filename, 'w') as csvfw:
    writer= csv.writer(csvfw, lineterminator= '\n')    
    for j in range(10):
        row_=[]
        x= str(j+1)
        for i in range(5):
            row_.append(row[i].count(x))

        writer.writerow(row_)
```

Comment: This worked like a charm with small tweeks due to version update.